webcam not working with Ubuntu 24.04
Webcam worked fine in Ubuntu 22.04 but after upgrade to 24.04 it works no longer. Any ideas?  The make is possibly XTP otherwise unknown

Idea: What do your logs say about it?

And what program(s) are you running?  If you're using Zoom, etc., give cheese a try -- it's perhaps a more lightweight option which you can use to see if your webcam is detected.

After using Cheese, webcam issues resolved themselves as mysteriously as they started

The X11 camera app on 24.04 is not enabled by default. I believe this terminal command will enable it:
sudo systemctl --user restart pipewire.service

Or:
sudo systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse.service

You can open the webcam app with the 'print screen' key.

Thanks for the suggestion but neither command had any effect except Printing the Screen as the button would suggest. I'm just using the Camera app like I did in 22.04 but now the camera is not detected

Not only does the Camera app no longer work but my password is no longer accepted now
